# Flutter GoogleMap Provider Context problem

Tags: google-maps, flutter, android-context, flutter-provider

I have a basic stateful app, with a GoogleMap base, which opens a BottomSheet on FloatingActionButton press. This is used as a settings tab to change/filter some lists which are then used by the map. My Provider is setup and values can be read/saved from both the GoogleMap dart file, and the BottomSheet dart file.

My main problem is how to provide context to the `Provider.of()` when not in the Widget Tree. For example, the GoogleMap runs `onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,` when finished loading. From within that function I want to pull a value from the Provider.of() a String, which tells me which list to use (which then populates the markers).

Things I'm trying to do:

- onMapCreated() pull value from the Provider (which is later used in a DB sqflite query)
- The bottomsheet needs to callback and `updateMarkers()` somehow, providing correct context

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;

    print(Provider.of<MyAppStateContainer>(context, listen:false).getSomeValue);  <---- Doesn't work
  ...
}
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyAppStateContainer>(
      create: (contextooo) => MyAppStateContainer(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My Map'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
          ),

          //Put in a stack widget so can layer other widgets on top of map widget
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Builder so we can get a CTX made, and then Provider.of() finds the Provider
              Builder(
                builder: (context) => GoogleMap(
                  mapType: Provider.of<MyAppStateContainer>(context).getMapType, <--- Works fine
                  markers: _markers,
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,

             ...
}
```

Provider:

```
class MyAppStateContainer extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyAppStateContainer();

  MapType _mapType = MapType.terrain;
  String _someValue;

  MapType get getMapType => _mapType;
  String get getSomeValue => _someValue;
}
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of passing back `BuildContext context` but sadly I'm forever getting this error about the Widget Tree:

`Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyAppStateContainer> above this MyApp Widget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that within `_onMapCreated`, you are trying to access the `Provider` using the context of `MyApp`, which is higher up the hierarchy of widgets than the `Provider` itself.

Convert your `home` widget (the Scaffold and everything below it) into a separate `StatefulWidget` and everything should start working, as you'll be using the context of the new widget, which is lower down the hierarchy of widgets than the `Provider`.

Comment: This answers my question, and the `Provider.of()` pulls the correct value now. However it has introduced a new issue- perhaps a new question, but still State related. The showBottomSheet UI now doesn't refresh when I change a value and call `mainAppState.setState()` - mainAppState a parameter passed with `this`

Comment: Ok, I fixed the issue. Many thanks for your answer. Problem solved